# c# null conditional member access operators

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, operators

We've recently received a project that was started using Visual Studio 2015. In the code there were places where developers used

> null conditional member access

operator. We are using Visual Studio 2013 and the code does not compile I've read the documentation from msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.140).aspx) and it states that this operator is not available with Visual Studio 2013. What's the logic behind this decision? The c# syntax depends on IDE? Shouldn't this be fixed for the same .net version?

Answer (score 2):

**This is simply a matter of what is available to use with different versions of C# and VS.**
This is not a bug. Clearly that solution is making use of the latest tooling and version c# available, you are not. The same applies if you where only using .net 2.0, you wouldn't be able to use Linq. Thus you have to accommodate it in some way

With VS 2013, it comes with `.net 4.5.1` and `C# 5`, you can

**Either** install `.net framework 4.6 and C#6` , then just update the targeted framework version in your projects

**or** use VS2015, then just update the targeted framework version in your projects

**or** laboriously reverse that syntax sugar back like the following:

```
someObject?.PossiblySafeProperty?.LessSafeNestedProperty
//to 
string valueYouWant = null;
if(someObject != null && someObject.PossiblySafeProperty!=null)
{
   valueYouWant = someObject.PossiblySafeProperty.LessSafeNestedProperty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as what the IDE can interpret yes, C# 6 syntax is only available in VS2015. However, using the latest compiler will fix your build errors(albeit not showing up correct in the IDE). And the .Net version has nothing to do with the languages syntax, only the libraries you can use in it. The logic behind the decision? To get you to upgrade to a newer product, same as offering Windows 10 for free. Microsoft wants you using the "latest and greatest" they have to offer.